# Thread Pool borrow

Tags: java

what happens when GenericObjctPool borrowObject can not borrow Object.

For example, if it is borrowed in arbitrary loop but thread pool is size is only 2.
Will it block the call on that call to borrowObject on non -availability Or enqueue it?

Comment: http://commons.apache.org/pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#borrowObject()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause for indefinite blocking - getPool().returnObject(MyRunnable) was missing

Answer (score 1):

Taken directly from [javadoc](http://commons.apache.org/pool/api-1.6/org/apache/commons/pool/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#borrowObject%28%29):

> If the pool is exhausted (no available idle instances and no capacity to create new ones), this method will either block (WHEN_EXHAUSTED_BLOCK), throw a NoSuchElementException (WHEN_EXHAUSTED_FAIL), or grow (WHEN_EXHAUSTED_GROW - ignoring maxActive). The length of time that this method will block when whenExhaustedAction == WHEN_EXHAUSTED_BLOCK is determined by the maxWait property.